# How can I fix the 'Module not found: Can't resolve 'os'' error when using Azure Application Insight with Next.JS and OpenTelemetry?

Tags: next.js, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

Would like to log a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/open-telemetry#manual-opentelemetry-configuration) app to [Azure Application insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-nodejs-exporter).

I have the following `instrumentation.ts` code

```
import { AzureMonitorTraceExporter } from '@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter'
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources'
import {
  NodeTracerProvider,
  SimpleSpanProcessor,
} from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node'
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions'

export async function register() {
  if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs') {
    const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
      resource: new Resource({
        [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'my-app',
      }),
    })

    // Create an exporter instance
    const exporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter({
      connectionString:
        process.env['APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'] ||
        '<your connection string>',
    })

    provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter))
    provider.register()
  }
}
```

This results in the following error when starting the app

`../../node_modules/@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter/dist-esm/src/export/statsbeat/statsbeatMetrics.js:6:0 Module not found: Can't resolve 'os'`

Any good ideas of an approach?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is due to missing dependency.

This `@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter` package depends on the `os` module, which is a built-in Node.js module.

Adding the `os` module to your project dependencies and by running the following command in your terminal you can resolve it.

```
npm install os
```

Another way is by updating your `@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter` package to the latest version by running the following command.

```
npm install @azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter@latest
```

And check the instructions in the [official Azure documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-nodejs) to log your Next.js app to Azure Application Insights using `OpenTelemetry`.

Traces

[image]

Trace logs:

[image]

Code to see log traces

```
import { TelemetryClient } from 'applicationinsights';
appInsights.trackEvent({ name: 'HelloWorldSuccess', properties: { message: 'Hello, World!' } });

throw new Error('Simulated error');

catch (error) 
{
   appInsights.trackException({ exception: error });
} 
finally {
   await appInsights.flush();
   console.log('Telemetry sent successfully.');
}
```

Placed the telemetry in this [location](https://i.imgur.com/vSnc9TM.png).